# Retention policy to TFS Code Search Server (Elastic Search)

Tags: elasticsearch, tfs, code-search

We have TFS 2017.3 with separate Code Search server.

We have huge TFS DB (about 1.6TB), in the code search server we have 700GB dis space.

After few weeks the disk space running out and the code search not work in the tfs.

After we increase the disk space the search back to work.
How can we make retention policy to delete old code search data (index)? we don't want to increased more the disk space.

Comment: Hi Shayki Abramczyk, any update on this case. Did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Comment: Hi Patrick! thank you for your answer, it's seen a long procedure and the truth it I didn't have enought to check it, anyway - I want to do this retention automatically, do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reduce the disk size after deleting the ES folders, reinstalling the code search extension, and sometimes had to run the `MissingIndexFolderTriggerCollectionIndexing.ps1`.

**But** - I came to the conclusion that it was not worth doing, the disk size was growing rapidly and reaching the original size, so I did not save anything.

Although Microsoft recommends giving disk space of 35% of the DB, it is not enough for us and we increase the size when the disk is full to the end (currently about 45% of the DB size).

**The conclusion - don't touch the ES, if the disk fills up then increase the disk size.**

Answer (score 0):

> Search indexing (**Code and Work Item**) works in 2 phases:
>
> - Bulk Indexing (BI) where the entire code and work item artifacts in    all projects/repositories under a Collection are indexed. This is a
>     time consuming operation and depends on the size of the artifacts
>     under the collection.
> - Continuous Indexing (CI) which handles all incremental updates to the    artifacts (add/updated/delete) and indexes them. This is
>     notification    based model where the indexer listens to TFS events
>     and operates    based on those event notifications. CI handles almost
>     all update    operations including CRUD operations at
>     Project/Repository/Collection    layer (such as Repository renames,
>     Project add/deletes, etc.). The    operation time for these CI would
>     depend again on the size of the    incremental update. BI always
>     precedes CI i.e. a CI will never    execute on a project/repository
>     until BI is completed for the same.

How to Clean-up Index Data and Re-index please follow below steps:

- Pause Indexing for all collections. Run the following script on TFS
  Configuration DB
  https://github.com/Microsoft/Code-Search/blob/master/PauseIndexing.ps1
- Login to the machine where the Elasticsearch (ES) is running
- Stop the ES service
- Delete the entire Search Index folder (something like,
  C:\TfsData\Search\IndexStore, or wherever you had configured it to
  be)
- Restart the TFS Job Agent service(s) on the AT machines
- Delete the following tables from each of the collection DBs

```html
DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnit]
DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEvent]
DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEventArchive]
DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_JobYield]
DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_TreeStore]
DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_DisabledFiles]
DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_ResourceLockTable]
```

- Restart the ES service
- Run this script on TFS Configuration DB:
  https://github.com/Microsoft/Code-Search/blob/master/ResumeIndexing.ps1
- Run this script (pick from the correct TFS release folder) on each of
  the collections:
  https://github.com/Microsoft/Code-Search/blob/master/TFS_2017Update2/MissingIndexFolderTriggerCollectionIndexing.ps1
- Try the last script on a smaller collection first (which has less
  number of repositories) so that you can verify that indexing happened
  correctly and the results are query-able.

More details please refer this blog in MSDN: **[Resetting Search Index in Team Foundation Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tapas_sahoos_blog/2017/09/11/resetting-search-index-in-team-foundation-server/)**